# Как взять отдельно первый элемент из только одного блока

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка

```html
<div class="wn-list-blocks">
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wn-list-blocks-content">
        <div class="wn-list-blocks-icon"></div>
        <div class="wn-bottom-title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как мне выбрать первый элемент с классом `.wn-list-blocks-icon` и, допустим, изменить фоновую картинку только для него одного, т.е. взять первый элемент с этим классом со всей страницы. А то, я пытаюсь взять его так `.wn-list-blocks-icon:nth-child(1)` и насколько я понял он берет так первый элемент из блока, но так как этот элемент первый во всех блоках на странице, то я изменяю картинку для всех, и получается следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а разве `document.querySelector('.wn-list-blocks-icon')` не находит самый первый попавшийся элемент в документе? Вы его пробовали?

Comment: @Август Думаю, речь о назначении свойств через  css.

Comment: @Август да, вы правы

Comment: аа, речь о чистом **css**? прошу прощения..

Comment: `.wn-list-blocks-content:first-child .wn-list-blocks-icon {` ну тогда вот так

Comment: @Август можете оставить этот как ответ на вопрос

Comment: @MidNightElf, я не особо люблю публичность, но раз Вы так просите..

Comment: @Август если у кого то еще будет такая непонятка, он может наткнутся на этот вопрос, но пропустить поскольку на него нет ответа. А так хотя бы видно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.wn-list-blocks-content:first-child .wn-list-blocks-icon
```